# Mapping the unit disc to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)=0,|\Im(z)|\geq1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have the following problem:

Find an injective and holomorphic function that maps de unit disc to the set given by

$$\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re{z}=0,|\Im{z}|\geq1\}.$$

I believe that this set is like a strip $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)\neq 0, |\Im(z)|<1\}$.

Probably I'm wrong, but we can take the map $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H}$ given by $f(z)=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$, the map $g:\mathbb{H}\to\{z=x+iy:-\pi/2<x<\pi/2,y>0\}$ given by $g(z)=\sin{z}$, then rotate the previous half-strip by $z\mapsto iz$ and then extend and compress the half-strip $\{z=x+iy:-\pi/2<y<\pi/2, x>0\}$ to $\{z=x+iy:-1<y<1\}$. Then I don't know how to continue to remove $x=0$. Maybe this idea is super wrong or simply is not the way to get a right answer.

Can you help me? or give me a hint to take a way not to complicated?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Your description of the set you want to map into is wrong: it should be $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : \Re(z)\ne 0\text{ or }\Im(z)<1\}$. Maybe a better way to view this set is to note that $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : \Re(z) = 0,\Im(z)\ge 1\}$ is a ray starting at $i$ pointing in the positive imaginary direction, and the set you want is the complement of that ray. Moreover, $g(z) = \sin z$ doesn't map to the set you describe (maybe you're thinking of $\log$?), and it's not injective anyway.

Comment: Your statement of the complement is incorrect.  The only thing excluded is the imaginary axis, except for the open segment from $i$ to $-i$, so the complement has lots of points with $|\Im{z}|\ge 1$  Your English is great, by the way.

Comment: @saulspatz I see it now. Thank you. But still can't figure it out how can i get the map

Comment: @nikilospuntajes It's been a long time since I've done one of these, but  I think the best approach is to try to find the inverse map.  To define an analytic function on $\mathbb H$ we want something involving $\log (z+i)$ and $\log(z-i)$ like $\log \frac{z+i}{z-i},$ I think, but I don't see how to to get something that maps onto $\mathbb D$ offhand.

Answer (score 2):

I.
 We consider a mapping $w=f(\zeta )$ $: \mathbb{H}\to T=\mathbb{H}\setminus \{w\in\mathbb{H}:\Re{w}=0,\Im{w}\geq1\},$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane. 
$T$ is a triangle, whose three vertices $w=i,-\infty,\infty$ with angles $2\pi, -\pi/2,-\pi/2$ respectively.
We want to find $f$ such that
$$
f(1)=i,\quad f(\infty)=-\infty, \quad f(0)=\infty.
$$
By the Schwarz-Christoffel formula $w=f(\zeta )$ will be of the form
\begin{align}
f(\zeta )&=i+A\int_1^\zeta \eta^{-\frac{1}{2}-1}(\eta -1)^{1-1}d\eta=i+A \int_1^\zeta \eta^{-\frac{3}{2}}(\eta -1)d\eta\\
&=i+A \int_1^\zeta \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\eta}}-\frac{1}{\eta\sqrt{\eta}}\right)d\eta\\
&=i+2A\left( \sqrt{\zeta }+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\zeta} }-2\right).
\end{align}
Here $A$ is some constant which should be determined so that $f(\zeta )$ is real for all negative real $\zeta $, since $f((-\infty,0))=(-\infty,\infty)$. Easy calculation shows that $A=\frac{i}{2}$. Thus we have $$
f(\zeta )=\frac{i}{2}\left(\sqrt{\zeta }+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\zeta }}\right).$$
II.
 Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the first quadrant and consider $\zeta =\varphi (\xi )=\xi ^2$ which maps $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{H}$. Then $$g(\xi )=(f\circ \varphi) (\xi )=\frac{i}{2}\left(\xi +\frac{1}{\xi }\right)$$
maps $\mathbb{Q}$ to $T$. By Schwalz reflection principle $g(\xi )$ maps $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{w\in\mathbb{C}:\Re{w}=0,|\Im{w}|\geq1\}$.

III.
 Now we consider $$\xi =\phi(z) =i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$ which maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{H}$. Then $$
w=(g\circ\phi)(z)=\frac{2z}{z^2-1}$$
maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{w\in\mathbb{C}:\Re{w}=0,|\Im{w}|\geq1\}$, which is a desired function.